# Set up Arduino to connect remotely

Tags: networking, arduino, nat

I have a Arduino connected to my home network using an Ethernet shield. I can control the board using simple URL request (e.g. 192.168.2.1/digitaloutput/8/1, turn pin 8 high etc.). I can only do that when connected to my home network.

What do I need to do connect to it remotely, say from my work computer? 
Is it possible to use the same method I am currently using (Arduino acting as a web server)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The network address you show is a "private" address, allocated by your router. On the global internet these addresses are "not routable", which means no-one else can get to your 192.168.2.1 (because there are lots of other copies of that address behind other home routers, and there would be no way to know which one to use). You need to find the public IP address of your router, and then use port-forwarding to redirect a port on your router to your Arduino. This is the easiest method to do what you want, but also the least secure.

You'd be able to say something like `http:<router-address>/digitaloutput/8/1` from your work computer and your router would forward the HTTP request on to your Arduino. Of course, anyone else in the world will be able to do that as well. A hint: there's no requirement that HTTP be served from the standard port 80.

Comment: There's one more thing: Arduino needs the router's address set as its default gateway. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: hey so I have the arduino ip set to the routers default gateway (192.168.1.1)...I have the NAT setting as follow: Source port 80, destination port 80, destination ip 192.168.1.1, Protocol TCP + UDP. When i enter my public ip address, xxx.xxx.xx.xx/digitaloutput/8/1, I just get sent to my router page.

Comment: The destination IP in your router's NAT table should point to your Arduino's IP address, 192.168.1.1 looks suspiciously like the IP address of your router from the LAN (private) side.

Comment: @DavidFlanagan He did _not_ mean to say to set the IP of your Arduino to the gateway IP (doing so will likely screw up your home network). Instead, the gateway must also be set inside the Arduino, for the routing to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up Arduino Webserver for remote access

http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,112955.0.html

or

http://community.cosm.com/node/112